# Downloading txt file from ftp server

Tags: android, ftp

I'm trying to download a simple txt file from a FTP-Server for quite some time now.

I'm using this code:

```
 String server = "ftp.server.com";
    int port = 21;
    String user = "user";
    String pass = "pass";

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {

        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        ftpClient.login(user, pass);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        String remoteFile1 = "/test.txt";
        File downloadFile1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "test.txt");
        OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
        boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
        outputStream1.close();

        if (success) {
            System.out.println("File #1 has been downloaded successfully.");
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But Android studio throws an error at me:

```
02-27 17:40:31.106  15373-15373/.upload_file_sample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:289)
        at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:203)
        at .upload_file_sample.MainActivity.DownloadDatabase(MainActivity.java:104)
        at .upload_file_sample.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:89)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4232)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17298)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And I can't find out why. I doublechecked my FTP login data, but they are correct. I'm using the apache-commons-net library btw. Can anybody help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your code inside the asynctask. Always make sure you don't make api call in main thread. Check this for asyntask example

[AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. So am I guessing right that the connection with the ftp server takes too much time so that the main thread is "waiting too long"?  I donwloaded the file now, and I see it on my phone, but if I plug the phone to my PC and browse it via USB the file doesn't appear. Do you know why?

Comment: From main thread you cannot make api call. It has to be called from different thread

Comment: Ok :) And why can't I see the file on my PC?

Comment: Did you downloaded file using asynctask?

Comment: yes the error disappeared and when I browse my phone with a filebrowser app I can see it, but when I plug it in with my USB cable I can't see the file on the phone

Comment: http://www.ajaxapp.com/2009/02/21/a-simple-java-ftp-connection-file-download-and-upload/ refer this link for file download

Answer (score 0):

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Networking task must not run in main thread, so you must put your task into a new thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Your code
    }
}).start();
```